# Samsung Overlay Component

Tags: android-permissions, samsung-mobile

Can anyone explain what below lines do when include in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.samsung.android.permission.SAMSUNG_OVERLAY_COMPONENT" />

<overlay
    android:priority="999"
    android:targetPackage="com.mon.android.font.alley" />
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a Font app for Samsung Themes?